# iPad App Distribuition

Tags: ios, ipad

I am currently having an app developed that I intend to sell, it will be for a specific type of busbiness and not the eveyday iPad users. With that being said I am not a large enterprise, so I cant urchase that, I do not feel for the price that I want to sell the app that it would be beneficail to place it on the app store, roughly around $1,000 for the application since it competes against solutions that cost 25k. I heard you could sell yourself on a website, but how could that be done? How can I sell a app without the appstore?

And yes I say addhoc, which only allows up to 100 ipads, enterprise soultion I do not fall in, since I looking at selling and not internal distribution and the appstore might not be the best bet for my app solution.

Thanks

A new developer

Answer (score 1):

Ad Hoc apps are not only limited to 100 devices, but expire (once or more per annum), and thus need to be re-signed with new provisions periodically to continue to function.

There is one more option for apps over $1000 in price.

For apps over $1000, another alternative to scale above 100 customers, as well as outside the App store even on stock OS devices, is to have each end customers buy their own $99/annum iOS Developer enrollment. That's not only less than 10% of the price of apps over $1k, and possibly less than the annual maintenance fee on the competing $25k software package, but also less than Apple's 30% App store percentage!

You could package your app as a shared library (without source code) inside a customized project, and just have the customer (or some developer service, such as yours for an annual fee) renew their certificates and provisions, and rebuild and reinstall the app, as long as the customer(s) keeps renewing their iOS enrollment.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much covered all of the available options.

As such, the app store seems to be the only suitable one, unless you have a Dun & Bradstreet Number and don't mind purchasing an enterprise developer license. (These are now only $299 that said, which seems like a small outlay considering the proposed cost of your app.)